# Scroll de Tkinter no funciona en mi ventana

Tags: tkinter, scroll

Antes de nada, es mi primera vez escribiendo en este sitio por si cometo alguna falta. Llevo una semana buscando información en este sitio y todas las soluciones que encuentro tienen un código similar y no me termina de funcionar.

Estoy haciendo una especie de calculadora que tiene varias pantalla para ir mostrando los diversos estados en los que está el cálculo, en cada una de estas pantallas se puede ver las variables y al lado un checkbutton con el que seleccionar esa variable para usarla en un cálculo posterior.
Debido a que el cálculo puede ser infinito puse una barra de scroll para poder moverme entre las variables, pero no soy capaz de hacer que esta barra de scroll me baje la ventana. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Os dejo una imagen por si es de ayuda para la explicación.

```
#Contruccion de pantallas
    # Agregar la pantalla donde se irán mostrando los cálculos hacia delante


    self.pantalla = Text(self.frame, width=50, height=10, background="lightgoldenrod4",
                         cursor="arrow")

    self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.pantalla, orient = VERTICAL)
    self.scroll.pack(side= RIGHT,fill=Y)
    self.scroll.config(command=self.pantalla.yview)
    self.pantalla.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)



    # Ubicar la pantalla en la ventana
    self.pantalla.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=15, padx=(5, 5), pady=0, sticky='WSNE')
    self.pantalla.grid_propagate(False)
```